# Find $E[Y\mid X]$and the best linear predictor $\ell(X)$, given uniform distribution on the set $B$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

> Let $(X,Y)$ be uniform on the region $B=\{(x, y) : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1, 0 ≤ y ≤
>  x^2\}.$ Find $E[Y\mid X]$and the best linear predictor $\ell(X)$.

I know that

$$E[Y\mid X]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_Y(y\mid X) \ dy.$$

But I don't know how to find $f_Y(y\mid X)$. Is $f_Y(y\mid X)$ the same as the marginal pdf of $Y$? If that's the case, then I can use that

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)},$$

and

$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\int_0^1 x^2 \ dx}=\frac{1}{1/3}=3,$$

also,

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^{x^2}3=3x^2.$$

So

$$f_Y(y)=f_Y(y\mid X)=\frac{3}{3x^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}.$$

But this is wrong answer.

---

**EDIT1:** The answer from Michael Hardy showed how trivial the first part of the problem was. But now I'm having problem with finding the best linear predictor. Here is what I've done:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables and correlation coefficient
>   $\rho$. The best linear predictor of $Y$ based on $X$ is given by
>
> $$\ell(X)=E[Y]+\rho\frac{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Y]}}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[X]}}(X-E[X])=E[Y]+\frac{\text{Cov}[X,Y]}{\text{Var}[X]}(X-E[X]).\tag1$$

I have that $$E[Y]=\int_0^1E[Y\mid X=x]f_X(x) \ dx=\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{2} \ dx = \frac{1}{6}$$

and trivially $E[X]=1/2, \ \text{Var}[X]=1/12$. Also,

$$E[YX]=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x^2}xy\cdot f(x,y) \ dy\,dx=3\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x^2}xy \ dy\,dx =\frac{1}{4}.$$

Hence, $(1)$ gives

$$\ell(X)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1/6}{1/12}\left(X-\frac{1}{2}\right)=2X-\frac{5}{6}.$$

But the correct answer is $\ell(X)=2X/3-1/5.$

Comment: The term "best linear predictor" seemed at best ambiguous, but your recent edit singles out a particular meaning: you want a function of $X$ whose graph is a straight line.

Comment: I've added a postscript to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional distribution is definitely not the same as the marginal distribution.

A better notation, for reasons I could go into, is $f_{Y\,\mid\,X} (y).$ This is the conditional density of $Y$ given the value of $X$, and it's uniform on the interval from $0$ to $X^2.$ Thus we have

$$
\operatorname E(Y\mid X) = \frac{X^2} 2.
$$

And for the record, the density is $f_{Y\,\mid\,X=x} (y) = \begin{cases} 1/x^2 & \text{if } 0\le y \le x^2, \\ 0 & \text{if } y<0 \text{ or } y>x^2.  \end{cases}$

So
$$
\operatorname E(Y\mid X=x) = \int_0^{x^2} y\cdot \frac 1 {x^2} \,dy = \frac{x^2} 2.
$$

**Postscript:** You wrote:
$$
\operatorname E[Y]=\int_0^1E[Y\mid X=x]f_X(x) \ dx=\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{2} \ dx = \frac{1}{6}
$$
But this assumes $X$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1].$ But you have
$$
f_X(x) = \int_0^{x^2} 3\, dy = 3x^2 \quad \text{for } 0\le x\le 1.
$$

Comment: So $f_{Y|X}(y)=f_Y(y|X)?$ In the formula, they condition $y$ on $X$, but then you say it's the same as conditioninng $X$ on $Y$. These notations are so confusing. Ok now when I see that other notation, it just made this problem a lot easier. Thanks.

Comment: And isn't this the same as just $E[Y]?$ Since we know that $Y\sim\text{unif}[0,X^2].$

Comment: Can you please see my edit?

Comment: With your postscript correction I get the answer $6X/5-3/10$, since my $E[Y]$ changed from $1/6$ to $3/10.$ I can't find the error :S

Comment: If the answer where $6X/5-3/10,$ then you would have $6\operatorname E(X)/5 - 3/10 = \operatorname E(Y) = 3/10.$ Is $\left(6\cdot \frac 3 4\right)/5 - \frac 3 {10}$ equal to $\frac 3 {10}\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: $$
\operatorname{E}(XY) = \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{x^2} xy (3 \, dy) \right) \,dx = \int_0^1 \frac {3x^5} 2 \, dx = \frac 1 4.
$$
$$
\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = \operatorname E(XY) - (\operatorname E X) (\operatorname EY) = \frac 1 4 - \frac 3 4 \cdot \frac 3 {10} = \frac 1 {40}.
$$
$$
\operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname E(X^2) - (\operatorname E X)^2 = \frac 3 5 - \frac 9 {16} = \frac 3 {80}.
$$
So you get the coefficient equal to $\dfrac{1/40}{3/80} = \dfrac 2 3. \qquad$

Comment: I simply got $f_X(x)=3x^2, \ f_{X,Y}(x,y)=3, \ E[Y]=3/10, \ E[X]=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\text{Var}[X]=\frac{1}{12},$ so $\text{Cov}[X,Y]=\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{10}=\frac{1}{10}.$ Finally $$\ell(X)=\frac{3}{10}+\frac{1/10}{1/12}(X-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{6X}{5}-\frac{3}{10}.$$

Comment: How did you get $\operatorname E X = \dfrac 1 2 \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Seems I made a mistake assuming $X\sim \text{unif}[0,1].$ I now see why $E[X]=3/4$. I got the correct answer now, thanks!